# Excel Version 2302: IMAGE Function not available

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, images

I have Excel Version 2302 (Build 16130.20714 Click-to-Run) running with Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise license and want to use the `=IMAGE()` worksheet function. The function does not show up in the formula editor, and gives me a "#NAME?" error when used.

Microsoft's roadmap says the feature was completely rolled out by [December 2022](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=Excel%2CDesktop%2CRolling%20out%2CLaunched&searchterms=image). The [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel?redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252f95c8d81d-08ba-42c1-914f-bca4603e1426) say that the feature was released with version Version 2211.

Do you have any ideas why the formula would not be available for me?

[image]

An example of the usage would be `=IMAGE("https://www.wikimedia.org/static/images/wmf.png")`.

Comment: Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise license    ....  Does your system Admin have you fully up to date.  I have an individual license and have the IMAGE function.

Comment: Version 2302 is not the latest - the latest is 2308.

Comment: IMAGE was also in 2307 when I tested.  I updated today.

Comment: Could you please share with us the complete formula you use in Excel?

Comment: @Allen_MSFTI added an example of the used formula, though I don't think it's an function usage problem, the function does not show up as an available formula.

Comment: @John Interestingly, I am still on 2302 and my office says "Up to date" when trying to update manually. I was not aware that system admins could define what newest versions are supported. Additionally, their release notes indicate that the image function was released much earlier already anyways.

Comment: You need to update Office to a newer version

Comment: @SebastianHojas - The current version is determined by which channel your Administrator has selected. 2302 is the current version for the `Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel`, likewise, 2308 is the current version for the `Current Channel`.

Comment: My work machine is on the Monthly Enterprise Channel, and despite [evidence](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-function-7e112975-5e52-4f2a-b9da-1d913d51f5d5?ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) suggesting that builds greater than 15608.10000 should have the function, I can confirm that 16529.20226 (2306) does NOT have the function.  **Which leads me only one conclusion the function has not yet reached the Enterprise channel.**

Answer (score 1):

> I have Excel Version 2302 (Build 16130.20714 Click-to-Run) running
> with Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise license and want to use the
> =IMAGE() worksheet function.
>
> Microsoft's roadmap says the feature was completely rolled out by December 2022. The release notes say that the feature was released with version Version 2211.

My own work machine is on the Monthly Enterprise Channel, and despite [evidence](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-function-7e112975-5e52-4f2a-b9da-1d913d51f5d5?ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) suggesting that builds greater than 15608.10000 should have the function, I can confirm that 16529.20226 (2306) does NOT have the function.

**Which leads me to only one conclusion, the IMAGE function, has not yet reached any of the Enterprise channels.** It is my belief that none of the Enterprise channels have this particular function at this time.

The current version is determined by which channel your Administrator has selected. 2302 is the current version for the `Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel`, 2308 is the current version for the `Current Channel`, and 2306 is the current version for the `Monthly Enterprise Channel`.

Source: [Update history for Microsoft 365 Apps (listed by date)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date)

Comment: "Which leads me to only one conclusion, the IMAGE function, has not yet reached any of the Enterprise channels" That assumption is false as I have the same version than you also on monthly entreprise channel, and I have the IMAGE function.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - In that case I cannot explain the reason, the current version of Excel, in the `Monthly Enterprise Channel` does not have the function on my system.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that Microsoft has not pushed newer functions to all (although they said they have already done it). My assumption could also be 100% wrong. Those are [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vz8b.png) and [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z1b2.gif) showing the image function on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do works.

I suggest the following (you or Office):

Uninstall Office completely.

Update Windows including Optional Updates completely.

Install the newest version of Office (V2308 as of the date of this post).

Do a final restart and test.

The above should work, but if not, have the Office give you a fresh Windows Image and start fresh.

Comment: Reinstalling Office won't change your channel, if you are limited, to what your IT Administrator assigned. I can't agree that a user on a network, using an Enterprise license of Office, should uninstall Office and attempt to bypass the current configuration of Office. [Besides the function should exist in the version they already have installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-function-7e112975-5e52-4f2a-b9da-1d913d51f5d5?ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: I would be inclined to fix the problem if what is there is not working.